# Convert loop to recursive function

Tags: python

I have written a python for loop iteration as show below. I was wondering if its possible to convert into a recursive function.

```
a = int(input("Please enter the first number: ")) 
b = int(input("Please enter the second number: ")) 
res = 0  
for i in range(a,b+1):
    temp = 1  
    for j in range(1,i+1):         
        temp = temp * j      
        res = res + temp      
print("Sum of products from 1 to each integer in the range ",a," to ",b," is: ",res)
```

I am expecting something like the below example:

```
def recursion(a,b):
res = 0 
   if condition or a while condtion
    ....
       return ....

   a = int(input("Please enter the first number: "))   
   b = int(input("Please enter the second number: ")) 
  print("Sum of products from 1 to each integer in the range ",a," to ",b," is: ",res)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Whether implemented iteratively or recursively, this is a very inefficient algorithm for the calculation. You might want to work it out in pencil and paper (for some small numbers) and take note of which work you're repeating.

Comment: "I was wondering if its possible to convert into a recursive function." Just for the sake of doing it? Or do you hope that this will solve some sort of problem? it will not make the code faster or easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = int(input("Please enter the first number: ")) 
b = int(input("Please enter the second number: ")) 

res = sum([x for x in range(int(a), int(b)+1)])

print(res)
```

My question is why do you need it to be recursive?
I ask that because this particular answer doesn't seem best approached through recursion.

if you need to use recursion

```
def recursive_sum(m,n):
    if n <= m:
        return n
    else:
        return n+recursive_sum(m, n-1)
```

EDIT:

the question asked included the sum of the factorial of a range, apologies for only including the sum portion.

```
def factorial(b):
    if (b==1 or b==0):
        return 1
    else:
        return (b * factorial(b - 1))

res = sum(map(factorial, range(a,b+1)))
```

The original code you're multiplying each value in the range by the product of the previous and summing.

range(5,10) for instance
total for the way the problem is written
res comes to 4500198
where the factorial sum = 4037880

If you print out just for value 5
you get 1+3+9+33+153 where !5=120
Which is the way you're trying to accomplish it?

Comment: Minor quibble: if you change that list comp to a generator expression (removing the `[` and `]`), it'll accomplish the same thing without first storing the whole list in memory. The bigger issue, however, is that you're not calculating the same thing that the asker is.

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this, imagine dividing the problem into smaller sub-problems

```py
def recursive_sum(a, b, res=0):
    if a > b:
        return res

    temp = 1
    for j in range(1, a+1):
        temp = temp * j
        res = res + temp

    return recursive_sum(a+1, b, res)

a = int(input("Please enter the first number: ")) 
b = int(input("Please enter the second number: ")) 

res = recursive_sum(a, b)
print(f"Sum of products from 1 to each integer in the range {a} to {b} is: {res}")
```